# sys.intern() failing to intern a string upon slicing

Tags: python, string, identity, python-internals

Why is sys.intern() failing to intern this string?

```
>>> from sys import intern
>>> "abcd"[:-1] == "abc"
True
>>> "abcd"[:-1] is "abc"
False
>>> intern("abc")
'abc'
>>> "abcd"[:-1] is "abc"
False  # Expected True
```

(on CPython 3.7.4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String literals are already interned, it's computed expressions that you'd need to intern manually.

```py
from sys import intern
print("abcd"[:-1] is "abc")  # False
print(intern("abcd"[:-1]) is "abc")  # True
print("abcd"[:-1] is "abc")  # False
```

`intern` doesn't mean 'whenever this string gets produced anywhere in the program change it to the interned reference', it just returns the interned reference for the string it's given.

```py
s1 = "abc"
s2 = "abc"
s3 = "abcd"[:-1]
s4 = intern(s3)
for s in [s1, s2, s3, s4]:
  print(id(s))
```

```
140002991598512
140002991598512
140002990838576
140002991598512
```

Comment: Thanks, yes I misunderstood. `eval(repr("abcd"[:-1]))` creates a string literal, is it equivalent to interning?

Answer (score 0):

Your expectations are wrong. Names, string-constants and similar are interned when the code-object is created ([here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ec13b9322d95a651606219469fc7b7e9c977f248/Objects/codeobject.c#L129-L133)) and not when any string-object is created.

The string for `"abcd"[:-1]` is created during the run time and thus not interned. Theoretically, if optimizer would evaluate this expression during the compile time, it could be interned, as it happens for example with

```
>>> "a"*5 is "aaaaa"  #True
```

But it is just an impelementation detail, for example

```
>>> "a"*4097
```

would no longer be evaluated during the compile time and thus not interned.